# Convert string representation of dictionary into dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I want to convert a string into dictionary. I've tried `eval` and `literal_eval` it doesn't work, since there are no quotes for keys.

```
str_to_convert = "{rpd.col_A : 'Type B', rpd_dev : 'Other, specify', rpd_form : 'Other'}"
```

Please note that rpd_dev: 'Other, specify', there is comma within the string which needs to be preserved.
How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: Where are you getting this string from?

Comment: The original string is "if ('rpd.col_A' == 'Type B') AND ('rpd_dev' == 'Other') AND ('rpd_form' == 'Other')" and I've managed to convert it to the above format

Comment: Please don't spam irrelevant tags

Answer (score 2):

To load it as JSON for example, you would need double quote `"` around each key and value, the easiest seems to use a regex

```
import re

str_to_convert = "{rpd.col_A : 'Type B', rpd_dev : 'Other', rpd_form : 'Other'}"
result = re.findall(r"([\w.]+)\s*:\s*'([\w\s]+)'", str_to_convert)
print(dict(result))  # {'rpd.col_A': 'Type B', 'rpd_dev': 'Other', 'rpd_form': 'Other'}
```

Comment: I have a case in which rpd_form : 'Other, specify' The above code fails for this scenario, since there is a comma within the string, how can I fix it?

Comment: Change to `([\w.]+)\s*:\s*'([\w,\s]+)'` or `([\w.]+)\s*:\s*'(.+?)'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [yaml](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) for something like this, just need to remove the braces and the commas.

```
import yaml

str_to_convert = "{rpd.col_A : 'Type B', rpd_dev : 'Other', rpd_form : 'Other'}"
res = yaml.load(str_to_convert.replace(", ", "\n").strip("{}"), Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'rpd.col_A': 'Type B', 'rpd_dev': 'Other', 'rpd_form': 'Other'}
```

**Note**

yaml is a third-party module so you need to installing by running:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some AST-lib for decode it - as example ast.literal_eval as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988251/12682934) or work with json - as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391807/12682934)