# Convert string representation of a dictionary which contains 'comma' in value into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to convert a string into dictionary. I've tried `eval` and `literal_eval` it doesn't work, since there are no quotes for keys.

```
str_to_convert = "{rpd.col_A : 'Type B', rpd_dev : 'Other, specify', rpd_form : 'Other'}"
```

Please note that rpd_dev: 'Other, specify', there is comma within the string which needs to be preserved.
How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: Didn't you asked this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544582/convert-string-representation-of-dictionary-into-dictionary

Comment: How looks expected ouput?